# Handle network protocol steps outside main listen-loop

Tags: networking, udp

I'm dealing with network programming (especially P2P systems) lately. The usual program I deal with, somewhere has something like this (running in it's own thread):

```
while True:
    handle(receive())
```

How do I deal with a series of dependent send/receive actions. For example when I want to have something like:

```
def inviteNode(receiver):
    send(receiver, INVITE)

    if receive() == OK:
        send(receiver, SOME_INFORMATION)
        ...
```

I mean several send/receive actions that depend on each other and have a certain order. It would be nice to have something like the `inviteNode()` above (because all steps of the protocol are at the same location in the code, and you can retrace the order just by looking at the code), but `receive()` calls outside of my listen loop just won't do it, because how should it be decided which `receive()` gets to receive the data.

Is having a global state the only solution for this? After doing the first `send(receiver, INVITE)` do I have to memorize somewhere, that I expect to receive an `OK` from that specific Node, I just sent the `INVITE` to? Isn't this very complex when I have several different of these dependent send/receive actions?

PS: Just to make sure: This is about UDP connections.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to use the sockets polling. You can use select() system call (cross-platform solution, but it's not so fast as it can be with special, system dependent API) or if you're targeting linux, you can try to use the epoll API.

The main idea is: you have some network sockets, those can be in different states (for example, the data can be received).

You can query this socket set for some events (Read,Write,Exception) and perform needed actions dependent on what you need.

For example, Nginx http server uses this architecture.

Also, you will need to save the context, for example which sockets should be notified and checked and what data was already received or sended, and other information you may need.

This is a bit complex but can do the job: [finite-state machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

- http://linux.die.net/man/2/select
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx